# (ECDSA-BouncyCastle)Cryptographic Algorithm Validation Program(CAVP) Testing: Digital Signatures

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, ecdsa, nist, secp256r1

We use ECDSA with secp256r1 in our project.Also we are using Bouncy Castle libraries. How can I CAVP using NIST test vectors?
I am newbie.Probably the answer is simple.
The link with the test vector is attached.
https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-algorithm-validation-program/digital-signatures#ecdsa2vs

[ECDSA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDW2O.png)

Thank's.

Comment: CAVP is not a verb. What do you want to do exactly? BC has been validated using CAVP test vectors already (see https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips_faq.html) but you need to join the early access program to see it.

Comment: Dear @BrunoRohée, how can i test ECDSA in our project? How can I show my managers that ECDSA has been tested? I want to show that the algorithm we use is working correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

BouncyCastle has been FIPS certified (https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/Certificate/2768), specifically https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/details?source=ECDSA&number=804 for ECDSA).

So whatever you're trying to validate has been validated a long time ago by people that actually know what they are doing.